# Does {1} = { 1, {1}}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

simple set question that I CAN'T decide on myself.

Is the statement {1} = {1, {1}} true or false?

I know that repeated elements in a set don't count, ie 1 = {1, 1, 1, ...} would be true.

My thought is that the statement is FALSE because {1, {1}} is a set with two separate elements: the number 1 and the set with the number 1. Or am I wrong?

Please help!

Comment: True. $1\in\{1\}$ but $1\notin1$ Hence $1\ne\{1\}$. So the rhs of your equation is a set with 2 elements, but the lhs is a set with 1 element. The argument you have is slightly incomplete: after all $\{1\}=\{1,1\}$ - both have the single element 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not the same! {1} is the set containing one, whilst 
{1, {1}} Is the set containing one BUT it also contains the set containing one!!

Another example to illustrate this principle is how $\emptyset$ is the empty set, but {$\emptyset$} is the set containing the empty set... Different things!! The latter has cardinality one and the former is empty!

Set theory is wonky!

Comment: Thank you! Accepted yours for the cardinality explanation - though Sam's was perfectly good too.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false as {1} represents a set which contains a single element 1. {1,{1}} represents a set containing two elements 1 and a set containing 1.

Hence both 1 and {1} would be subsets of {1,{1}}